# working of static method

Tags: java

I want to know that, when we call the the static method defined in the class animal (ie. `initialize_animal()`) pointed at by 1, then on the execution of the main function the output is: `Default height 0`.

But if we put the statement 1, just below the statement 2 then we execute the main function the output is: `Default Height 20`.

Please tell me the reason for this difference in the two outputs.

```
class test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           animal.initialize_animal();    // (1)
           cat obj=new cat();          //2
           System.out.println("Default height:" +obj.getheight());
      }
}
class animal {
     static int Height;

     public animal() {
          Height=0; 
     }

     public int getHeight() {
         return Height; 
     } 

     public static void initialize_animal() {
         Height=20;
     }
}
class cat extends animal {
     String Sound;

     Public cat() {
          Sound="mew";
     }

     public String getSound() {
          return Sound;
     } 
}
```

Comment: [tag:javascript] has nothing to do with [tag:java].

Answer (score 1):

On the first way, you call initialize_animal, which sets the Height to 20. THEN you make a new animal and when that is created, the height gets set to 0 in the animal constructor.

The second way, you create the animal first and THEN set the height to 20.

Comment: yes i actually want to know what the 1 statement causes. when it is executed and ater we create a object of type cat.

Comment: What do you mean "what the statemend causes"? It causes the height to get set to 20...

Comment: so after tat if we create any number of object all will show the output 0 according to your first explanation.

Comment: Yes, unless you call your initialize_animal method again, or set the height in any other way. Because you set the Height variable as static, it will remain the same for ALL of your animal objects. An easy way to think of it is that the variable belongs to the class and not the individual objects. http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/instance_vs_class_members.html

Answer (score 1):

Because height is qualified as static. There is only one "height" throughout the execution of your program.